# "Where can I find X ROM" questions should be treated like shopping questions

Tags: discussion, scope

...because that's what they are.

Granted, there's not a "store" but it's the same idea as "where can I get the cheapest Android phone".

If nothing else, it's someone trying to crowdsource their web search.

That said, a canonical "where can I find Android ROMs" question (Community Wiki) would be a good idea.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't flash ROMs to my Android devices, so I wouldn't be a good person to do that.

Comment: How do you feel about questions like [Are there any known rom(s) with full device encryption incorporated?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/are-there-any-known-roms-with-full-device-encryption-incorporated), where they're looking for something specific?  I'm not sure whether to close them as dupes of the wiki question or not.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Still not good, I'd say. Once again they've chosen their solution ahead of time. A better question would be "how can I do full device encryption?" Still and all, I'd be inclined to let that question stand if they also include information about what ROMs they've already checked out.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds good to me, and I agree that individual requests are basically shopping recs.  I went ahead and created the question: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device/17153#17153)

Comment: Good idea. My answer would be "ROM Manager" :D

Comment: @BryanDenny Good thought, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds good to me, except for the case where a user wants to restore their phone to original stock. I feel that asking where to find the stock image is a good question, since stock won't change (while ROMs are constantly created/updated/abandoned).